# Django loop through list

Tags: python, django, jinja2

How do you loop trough a list in Django templates with a for loop?
my problem is with trying to fetch list.0 list.1 list.2
But when running the code i don't get anything

```
{% for i in range %}
    {% for key, value in list.i.items %}
        {{ key }}
        {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

where i should be list.0-2 but it doesn't show anything on screen

Comment: what is variable list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a list containing a dict?
Just use the following code

```
{% for element in lst %}
     {% for key, value in lst.items %}
       {{ key }} --> {{ value }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: functions don't have brackets in templates. items is correct.